# Vacuum storage bags?

Tags: filament, storage

Does anyone use "space saver" style vacuum storage bags to keep fillament dry? I picked up some Ziploc space bags, but they are larger than ideal. Would probably fit 2.5 spools. I would love a smaller version just big enough for one spool.

Comment: /wondering if buying a used cigar humidor would be over the top /

Answer (score 2):

I've read people are using them, makes sense, the less air you contain, the less moisture would be in the bag. Myself, I'm using IKEA ziplock bags (and moisture absorbing sachets), they come in many sizes.

Comment: I've been using 1 gal ZipLock bags. They are *just big enough* to put a filament roll into. I then close the zipper almost all the way, leaving enough room to put a plastic drinking straw into, and then use the straw to draw out as much air as I can, closing the zipper the rest of the way as I pull the straw out. I then put the roll back into the original box. While a Ziplock bag won't keep all air/moisture out, it does a pretty good job. I also leave the desiccant bag in with the filament to help with any moisture which may seep in.

Answer (score 1):

I have a commercially available product known as a foodsaver (TM) which removes the air from the bag and really squeezes tightly around the spool. The width of the bags I use barely takes the typical spool but it does fit with a little elbow grease.

I include a bag of desiccant in each bag to pull any residual moisture.

It's a good idea to use the cut-to-length bags on a roll, which allows you to add excess length, as you have to cut and toss away the previous seal each time you use the spool.

I too purchased the big honking bags and never built the structure I planned to use with it.

So many compromises regardless of the method used. I've since switched to Sealtite Storage Bins from Target. They have a gasket around the lid and I've increased the bag of desiccant in each one. They stack well too.